# Definability of nilradical in the model theory of rings

Tags: reference-request, ac.commutative-algebra, model-theory

I am looking for a reference dealing with the first-order definability of the nilradical of a commutative ring. The only thing I have found so far is [an exercise](https://books.google.com.br/books?redir_esc=y&id=Rf6GWut4D30C&q=nilradical#v=snippet&q=398&f=false) in Wilfrid Hodges' book *Model Theory* (Exercise 8.5.1), whose solution provides an example of a commutative ring whose nilradical is not first-order definable.

> Is there a class of commutative rings whose nilradical **cannot** be defined by a first-order formula (in the theory of rings)?

Comment: I am little bit confused. It seems like Exercise 8.5.1 shows that the nilradical cannot be defined by a first-order formula in the class of *all* commutative rings. I am missing something?

Comment: @LevonHaykazyan No, you are understanding correctly; the point is that the exercise provides an isolated example. I would like to have an entire class of examples. (on the other hand, note that the nilradical is definable in some classes of commutative rings: for example, the formula φ(t):t=0 trivially defines the nilradical in reduced rings.)

Answer (score 4):

For example, the nilradical is not definable in the class of all rings (or even local rings).
Let say that a ring is **small** if every element is either nilpotent or invertible for example $\mathbb{Z}/p^n$ for every prime $p$ and number $n$. Assume that there is a formula defining the nilradical then since being invertible is a first-order property of an element we get that being small is a first-order property of rings. But this is false. To see this take a non-principle ultraproduct $R:=\prod_{\mathcal{F}}\mathbb{Z}/p^n$.
If being small was a first-order property of rings it would have been preserved by ultraproducts and then $R$ was small.
However, the element represented by the constant series on $p$ in $R$ is not nilpotent nor invertible.